# Finding Mismatch Between Two SQL DataTables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql data tables named as `tmptable1` and `tmptable2`
I am trying to display data that have in `tmptable1` but not in `tmptable2`
I have written following query but it is showing blank result but I know there is one record that have in `tmptable1` but not in `tmptable2` 
following is my query.What's wrong I am doing.

```
select * from tmptable1 where name not in(select name from tmptable2 where status='active')
```

Comment: hi I am using MS SQL

Comment: can u pls specify the full query

Comment: sample data can be name, address, city, mobilno and country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also take advantage of [EXCEPT and INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql):

The following gives you the names that exist in `tmptable1` but not in `tmptable2`:

```
SELECT name FROM tmptable1

EXCEPT

SELECT name FROM tmptable2
```

Whereas this gives you the common names:

```
SELECT name FROM tmptable1

INTERSECT

SELECT name FROM tmptable2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from tmptable1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tmptable2 t2
    where t1.name = t2.name
    and t2.status = 'active'
    );
```

Alternatively, you can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.*
from tmptable1 t1
left join tmptable2 t2
    on t1.name = t2.name
    and t2.status = 'active'
where t2.name is null;
```